# Regex to eliminate many lines of text with an known start and stop string

Tags: regex

I am attempting to eliminate all of the text between two specific strings of text with a single regex command.  The original text looks like this:

```
<html>
  <!-- template name: text.tpl -->
  <head>
    <title>Cross-Collection Search</title>    
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <script src="/t/text/textclass.js" language="JavaScript"></script>
    <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="/t/text/textclass.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/t/text/textclass-specific.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="/t/text/bbagWindow.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     <!-- 

     window.name = "mainwindow";

     //-->
    </script>    
  </head>

  <!-- -------------------------------------------------- -->

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">

  <!-- -------------------------------------------------- -->

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr> 
    <td height="54" class="hdrcolor" background="/t/text/graphics/hdr-bg1.gif">
    <a name="top"></a>
    <a href="http://ecfr.gpoaccess.gov/cgi/t/text/text-idx?c=ecfr;c=sampletc;cc=ecfr;xc=1;sid=75189253ab69c67a4a0484a5acb0c128;tpl=%2Fusr%2Flocal%2Fdlxs%2Fweb%2Ft%2Ftext%2Fhome.tpl" target="_top"><img src="/t/text/graphics/umdlt-smbanner.gif" border="0"></a></td>
     <td height="54" class="hdrcolor" align="right" valign="top" background="/t/text/graphics/hdr-bg2.gif">
      <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
        <tr>



          <td align="right" nowrap valign="top" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">&nbsp;<font size="-1"><a class="globnav" href="">Authorized user login</a></font>&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFCC66" nowrap>&nbsp;<font size="-1"><a class="globnav" href="javascript:popupBBagWindow( 'http://ecfr.gpoaccess.gov/cgi/t/text/text-idx?c=ecfr;c=sampletc;cc=ecfr;xc=1;sid=75189253ab69c67a4a0484a5acb0c128;page=bbaglist' , true )">View 
            bookbag</a></font>&nbsp;</td>

        </tr>
      </table>
          <font class="navinfo" size="2"><br>your bookbag has <strong>0</strong> items</font>&nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>

<!-- BEGIN rows outlining the navigation proper  -->

<!-- this row contains a table controlling layout for the top border lines of the navbar   -->

  <tr> 
    <td class="navcolor" colspan="2" align="left" height="1" nowrap>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr> 
      <!-- home  -->
          <td width="70" height="1" align="center" nowrap><img src="/t/text/graphics/plug.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0"></td>        
          <td width="1"><img src="/t/text/graphics/plug.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0"></td>
      <!-- search  -->
          <td width="90" height="1" align="center" nowrap><img src="/t/text/graphics/plug.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0"></td>
      <td width="1"><img src="/t/text/graphics/plug.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0"></td> 
      <!-- browse -->
          <td width="75" height="1" align="center" nowrap><img src="/t/text/graphics/plug.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0"></td>
      <!-- blankspace  -->
      <td width="75" height="1" align="center" nowrap><img src="/t/text/graphics/plug.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0"></td>
      <!-- help  -->
      <td width="75" height="1" align="center" nowrap><img src="/t/text/graphics/plug.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0"></td>
        </tr></table>
    </td>
  </tr>


<!-- this row contains a table controlling layout for the nav tabs themselves   -->
  <tr> 
    <td class="navcolor" colspan="2" align="left" bgcolor="#666699" height="23" nowrap>
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr> 
          <!-- home  -->
          <td width="70" height="23" align="center" nowrap><font class="navlinks" color="#ffffff"><a href="http://ecfr.gpoaccess.gov/cgi/t/text/text-idx?c=ecfr;c=sampletc;cc=ecfr;xc=1;sid=75189253ab69c67a4a0484a5acb0c128;tpl=%2Fusr%2Flocal%2Fdlxs%2Fweb%2Ft%2Ftext%2Fhome.tpl" class="nav">Home</a></font></td>
          <!-- search  -->      
          <td width="90" height="23" align="center" nowrap><font class="navlinks" color="#000000"><a href="http://ecfr.gpoaccess.gov/cgi/t/text/text-idx?c=ecfr;c=sampletc;cc=ecfr;xc=1;sid=75189253ab69c67a4a0484a5acb0c128;page=simpleext" class="nav">Search</a></font></td >
           <!-- browse  -->

           <td width="90" height="23" align="center" nowrap><font class="navlinks" color="#ffffff"><a href="http://ecfr.gpoaccess.gov/cgi/t/text/text-idx?c=ecfr;cc=ecfr;xc=1;sid=75189253ab69c67a4a0484a5acb0c128;tpl=browse.tpl" class="nav">Browse</a></font></td >

          <!-- blankspace  -->
          <td width="50" height="23" align="center" nowrap>&nbsp;</td >
          <!-- help  -->
          <td width="70" height="23" align="center" nowrap><font class="navlinks" color="#ffffff"><a href="/t/text/help" target="helpwin" class="nav">Help</a></font></td >
        </tr>
      </table>
         </td >
        </tr>

<!-- this row contains the table that controls layout for the lower nav border lines   -->

<tr> 
    <td class="navhrcolor" colspan="2" align="left" height="1" nowrap bgcolor="#999999">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr> 
          <td width="70" height="1" align="center" nowrap><img src="/t/text/graphics/plug.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0"></td>
          <td width="1"><img src="/t/text/graphics/plug.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0"></td>
          <td width="90" height="1" align="center" nowrap><img src="/t/text/graphics/plug.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0"></td>
          <td width="1"><img src="/t/text/graphics/plug.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0"></td>
          <td width="75" height="1" align="center" nowrap><img src="/t/text/graphics/plug.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0"></td>
          <td width="75" height="1" align="center" nowrap><img src="/t/text/graphics/plug.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0"></td>
        </tr></table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" width="100%">
      <tr> 
        <td valign="top" nowrap>



    <hr size="1">
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>

    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="15">
      <tr> 
        <td>    

          <br>
<strong><span class=mainheader>
```

The completed text after a regex search and replace needs to look like this:

```
<html>
<strong><span class="mainheader">
```

For some reason, just using the following does not work.  Why?

```
<html>(.*)<strong><span class=mainheader>
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need dot-all mode on (to make `.` matches new line character), or just replace `.` with `[\s\S]` (which ensures that all characters are matched regardless of whether your language support dot-all mode or not).

Comment: +1 I like the idea of using `[\s\S]` to get around differing syntax for dotall.  It should be noted that a search and replace with the current regex will still likely produce a blank string though.

Comment: @NolenRoyalty: It depends on how the replacement is done (if it uses captured text as replacement, then it will be fine).

Comment: you're right, I wasn't thinking.  It seems like a slightly odd solution, but it would certainly solve op's problem.

Comment: @NolenRoyalty: Why did you delete your post? I think it is a valid answer regardless of the language.

Comment: Here is a better example.  What if I have this text: